# Extract position of "+" and "*" symbol in string using R

Tags: r, regex, string, symbols

I am looking for a manner to extract the position of "*" and "+" symbols in R string.

```
test <- "x+y"
unlist(gregexpr("+", test))
[1] 1 2 3
unlist(gregexpr("y", test))
[1] 3
```

It returns the position of x or y but returns all positions for + or *.

Thank you!

Comment: since you are `unlist`ing your results, it seems that you only have one expression per line, hence use `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr`. For the case of `+` symbol, you just need to escape it as it is a metacharacter: `regexpr('\\+', test)`

Comment: Another way to escape it is `[+]` which is a "character class" in [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272); this is also necessary for `[*]`. Using this, you can look for *either* (not differentiating) with `[+*]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fixed = TRUE`, by default it is `FALSE` and uses the regex mode where `+` is a metacharacter.  According to `?regex`

> `+` - The preceding item will be matched one or more times.

> `*` - The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.

```
unlist(gregexpr("+", test, fixed = TRUE))
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other base R workarounds

```
> which(unlist(strsplit(test, "")) == "+")
[1] 2

> which(utf8ToInt(test) == utf8ToInt("+"))
[1] 2
```

Comment: This solution appears quicker than the other one. Thank you!